# inculding a video with transparency on a website

Tags: html, transparency, brackets, webm, cinema-4d

I have some cinema4D animations with a transparent background that I want to put on a website. I exported the animation as single .pngs (with an alpha channel) and put them in adobe premiere and exported them as .webm
I work with brackets, but when I include them in the code, they either don't show up at all, or with a black background.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: <video autoplay src="filename.webm" loop muted playsinline></video>

Comment: Try adding css background: transparent property to the video element.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try transparent **GIF**
You can make it in photoshop (from png sequences) and use it in your website.
Make sure to export with transparent background!